# python: spyder: cannot edit a previous command in the Console while running ipdb

Tags: python, spyder

I am trying python spyder on linux ubuntu (VM on windows) and have tried both spyder 3.2.6 installed with apt-get and an anaconda installation (latest 3.3.2).
In Both cases, if I hit the debug button `>||`, set a breakpoint and hit the continue button `>>`, so ipdb is runs in the Console, then, I cannot edit the commands there:

For instance, if I write (`ipdb>` being the prompt)

```
ipdb> p tar1
*** NameError: NameError("name 'tar1' is not defined",)
```

when I meant `p var1`,
I want to be able to recall the wrong command using the up arrow and move using the left arrow along the command line to change the 't' to 'v' (to get `p var1`).
Recalling the previous command using the up arrow works, but moving toward the left to change to 't' to 'v' does not.
It seems there is some strange "force" dragging the cursor back to the end of the line (I can see the cursor moving left when pressing the left arrow, but immediately being placed back at the end of the line).
Using backspace (deleting instead of moving along) works.

Trying the select some text in the Console also behaves strangely, so I am suspecting some keyboard/Mouse interaction problem, But so far, I have only experienced it on Spyder

This issue makes spider pretty unusable to me

Any clue of what this could be related to?

Comment: same problem in the jupyter Qtconsile...

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) We're working to develop an easier to use debugger in Spyder 4, to be released later this year. However we can't do anything about it for Spyder 3, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the case in Spyder 3.3.2 in Windows as well.  Unfortunately, this is known behavior in ipdb and will not be resolved until Spyder 4 is released later this year.  For more details see [the official issue on Github](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/8538).

Comment: Just tryed version 4.0.0b2 via anaconda install, but still the same behaviour... I am really looking forward a nice  interactive environment like matlab(including plotting) which this bug fix would be a part of.... Any news?